# Substituitions prove using structural induction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, substitution

The exercise is:

> Prove that if σ and τ are two substitutions that agree on the
>   variables of the term t, then tσ = tτ. Use structural induction on t.

I understand the principle of substitutions, but I don't really understand the rest.

Does tσ = tτ mean for example: if tσ = f(x,y), tτ = f(x,y) then j(k(t))σ = j(k(f(x,y))) and j(k(t))τ = j(k(f(x,y))) ? I don't really understand what to show.

And I know what structural inducation is, but I don't understand how to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have two substitutions $\sigma$ and $\tau$, that is to say two injective maps from  alphabet $\Sigma$ to alphabet $\Sigma'$, say.

Instead of writing "$t\sigma = t\tau$", which might be confusing, I prefer to extend $\sigma, \tau$ naturally to a function $\sigma^*$ from the set $Term(\Sigma)$ of terms over $\Sigma$ to the set $Term(\Sigma')$. This allows us to write "$\sigma^*(t) = \tau^*(t)$" instead.

Formally, $\sigma^*$ is defined by induction on the construction of terms over alphabet $\Sigma$ as follows :

- **Case $t = x$ for $x \in \Sigma$ :**
  We set $\sigma^*(t) = \sigma^*(x) := \sigma(x)$.
- **Case $t = f(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ for $t_1, \dots, t_n \in Term(\Sigma)$ :**
  We set $\sigma^*(t) := f\big(\sigma^*(t_1), \dots, \sigma^*(t_n)\big)$.

> Now, it becomes straightforward : since by hypothesis $\sigma = \tau$ (**Edit : wrong**, the hypothesis is weaker), we have $\sigma^* = \tau^*$. Hence, we get $\sigma^*(t) = \tau^*(t)$, qed.

Suppose $\sigma$ and $\tau$ agree on the variables $V = Var(t)$ of $t$. We show by induction on the construction of $t$ that $\sigma^*$ and $\tau^*$ agree on all terms $t$ whose variables are in $V$ :

- **Case $t = x$ for $x \in V$ :**
  We have $\sigma^*(t) = \sigma(x) = \tau(x) = \tau^*(t)$.
- **Case $t = f(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ for $t_1, \dots, t_n \in Term(\Sigma)$ :**
  Since $Var(t) = Var(t_1) \cup \dots \cup Var(t_n)$, the variables of $t_i$ belong to $V$ for all $i$. We can hence apply the induction hypothesis and we get $\sigma^*(t_i) = \tau^*(t_i)$ for all $i$. But now, 
  $$\sigma^*(t) := f\big(\sigma^*(t_1), \dots, \sigma^*(t_n)\big) = f\big(\tau^*(t_1), \dots, \tau^*(t_n)\big) = \tau^*(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$t$ is a *term* i.e. either a variable ($x,y,\ldots$) or a constant $c$ or a "complex" term built with a *function* symbol (e.g. $fx$).

$\sigma$ is a substitution and $t \sigma$ means the result obtained applying substitution $\sigma$ to term $t$.

Example: for $\sigma := [x \leftarrow y]$ and $t := fx$ the term $t \sigma$ will be:

> $fx [x \leftarrow y] = fy$.

Thus, to prove that $t \sigma = t \tau$ means to show that the terms obtained from the two substitutions applied to term $t$ are the same.

To prove it by induction means to use induction on the *complexity* of the term $t$:

> *(i) Base case*: either $t$ is $x$ or $t$ is $c$.

Both sub-cases are obvious, because $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on the free variables of $t$.

> *(ii) Induction step*: assume that property holds for terms: $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ and prove it for term: $ft_1 \ldots t_n$.

Assume for simplicity $n=1$, i.e. $t := f t_1$. The induction hypotheses is that $t_1 \sigma = t_1 \tau$. Thus:

> $t \sigma = (f t_1) \sigma = f (t_1 \sigma)$, because substitutions do not act on function symbols, $= f (t_1 \tau)$, by induction hypotheses, $= (f t_1) \tau= t \tau$.

Comment: Thank you, and how should I do that with structural induction?

Comment: Because for me its obvious that σ:=[x←y] and τ:=[x←y] have the same outcome

Comment: What is c?
And what is t1,...tn? Are they other terms? So to prove that tσ=tτ holds for every term?

Comment: @Kingvinst -  Yes and yes....

Comment: Is this a correct proof / final answer for the question:

To prove it by induction means to use induction on the complexity of the term t:

Base case: either t is x (variable) or t is c (constant). Both cases are obvious, because τ and σ agree on the free variables of t.

For σ:=[x←y] and τ:=[x←y] and t:=x both terms - tσ and tτ - will be x[x←y]=y

Inducation step: we assume the property holds for the terms t1,...,tn. Now we show it holds for f(t1),...f(tn).

For σ:=[x←y] and τ:=[x←y] and t:=fx both terms - tσ and tτ - will be fx[x←y]=fy

Comment: @Kingvinst - induction step: not exactly.